# CONCAT('a', 'b') vs 'a' || 'b' in Teradata

Tags: sql, string, concatenation, teradata

Noticed, that there are two ways to concatenate strings in Teradata.

- `CONCAT('a', 'b')`
- `'a' || 'b'`

As every second counts, which one is faster?

```
SELECT CONCAT('a', 'b'), 'a'||'b';
```

or these are compiled to the same operation?

Comment: The most likely are executed under the hood using the same code and logic.  Pick whichever version suits the query more.

Comment: `||` is ANSI SQL and expected to be portable. However, `CONCAT()` is pretty popular too. (However, for concat('abc', null) , some products return 'abc', while others return null.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are completely interchangeable and none gives any performance boost.